# Batch execution of hive scripts causing issue

Tags: hive, hiveql

I will start off by saying, if you need more information, please let me know, I am trying to keep this as simple as possible, but I can provide full details if required.

So I have a base hql script that looks like this

```
INSERT INTO TABLE ${DB_NAME}.${TABLE_NAME} PARTITION (SNAPSHOT_YEAR_MONTH,SNAPSHOT_DAY)
SELECT 
`(snapshot_year_month|snapshot_day|row_num)?+.+`,
'${SNAPSHOT_YEAR}' as snapshot_year_month,
'${SNAPSHOT_DAY}'  as snapshot_day
FROM
(SELECT
*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY  ${PK} ORDER BY time_s DESC,wanted_c DESC ) AS row_num  
FROM
( SELECT ${COL} FROM ${SOURCE_DB_NAME}.${SRC_TABLE_NAME} WHERE (concat(snapshot_year_month,snapshot_day) = '${LOWER_LIMIT}${LOWER_LIMIT_DAY}')
UNION ALL
SELECT ${COL} FROM ${SOURCE_DB_NAME}.${SRC_TABLE_NAME} WHERE (concat(snapshot_year_month,snapshot_day) >'${LOWER_LIMIT}${LOWER_LIMIT_DAY}' and concat(snapshot_year_month,snapshot_day) <='${UPPER_LIMIT}${UPPER_LIMIT_DAY}') ) B) A 
WHERE A.row_num = 1 ;
```

This base script generates several hundred hive queries that need to be run.  One important part to note is the `WHERE a.row_num = 1` which prevents any combination of `${PK}` from having more than one row.  Now, these scripts are successfully generated and stored in hql files.  I then have a batch script to run all of these hive scripts

```
for f in *.hql ; do beeline -u 'myserverinfo' -f $f ; done
```

Now, if only a couple files are in the folder, everything works as intended.  However, if I drop 500 hqls in the folder, no duplicates (which are correctly removed when only a couple hqls are in the folder) are correctly removed.

So for example,

if I have a dataset thats like this

```
| my_pk1 | my_pk2 | time_s | wanted_c | other cols... |
    1        1        1          1           ...
    1        1        2          5           ...
    1        1        6          6           ...
```

If I have just a couple hql files being run with my batch script, it will correctly condense that to just -

```
| my_pk1 | my_pk2 | time_s | wanted_c | other cols... |
    1        1        6          6           ...
```

However, if I drop 500+ hql scripts to be run, the partitions are correctly inserted, all hql scripts run and have data, however they all have duplicate primary keys, and that same table, with the EXACT same hql script would output

```
| my_pk1 | my_pk2 | time_s | wanted_c | other cols... |
    1        1        1          1           ...
    1        1        2          5           ...
    1        1        6          6           ...
```

This makes absolutely no sense to me.  Any ideas on what could be happening? I'm sorry if this makes no sense.

Comment: seems strange..have you tried running the problematic queries individually, by passing in the variable values?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Sorry if I wasn't clear, the scripts being run have no variables in them (They just have thousands of columns, so no point in me showing those).  I have a seperate workflow to generate hundreds of HQLs from the base I posted (This works fine, and if I execute any single hql script individually, it works correctly).  So there are no variables.